# TikZ - 3D surface plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw something like this
[image]

For the moment I just managed to draw a 3D plate and I don't know how to do it with the 3D sinus curves.
I managed to draw something like that, but I don't know how to do for have 2 color in the curve and the same shape. It's not that good !!

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[hide axis]
\addplot3 [
domain=-2:2,
domain y = -2:2,
samples = 40,
samples y = 40,
surf,
fill=pink,
faceted color = teal] {-exp(-(x^2+y^2)/1.3};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Could you help me?!

Comment: Please show what you have tried and describe where you are stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what your question is - it seems like you did it. -anyway here the surface is with two colors and some curves. Please ask, if I have misunderstood or you have trouble adding the rest.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={violet}{rgb255=(25,25,122) rgb255=(238,140,238) color=(white)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
 f(\x,\y)=-exp(-(\x^2+\y^2)/1.3;
}]
\begin{axis}[
view={30}{20},
mesh/interior colormap name=violet,
colormap/viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2.5, zmax=0,
]
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-2:2,
samples=40,
samples y=40,
surf,
] {f(\x,\y)};
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
samples=40,
samples y=1,
smooth,
] ( x , -2 , {f(\x,0)});
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
samples=40,
samples y=1,
smooth,
] ( x , -2 , {f(\x,1)});
\draw[->, thick] (0,-2,0) -- node[font=\tiny, pos=0.7, right=-2pt]{$W_{\text{max}}$} (0,-2, {f(0,0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Surface graph with curves at the side]

Edit with thickness:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={violet}{rgb255=(25,25,122) rgb255=(238,140,238) color=(white)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
 f(\x,\y)=-exp(-(\x^2+\y^2)/1.3;
}]
\begin{axis}[
view={30}{20},
mesh/interior colormap name=violet,
colormap/viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2.5, zmax=0,
]
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
domain y=-2:2,
samples=40,
samples y=40,
surf,
] {f(\x,\y)};
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
domain y=0:360,
samples=40,
samples y=2,
surf,
] (x,-2,{f(\x,-2)-0.05*sin(\y r)});
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
domain y=0:360,
samples=40,
samples y=2,
surf,
] (2,x,{f(\x,2)-0.05*sin(\y r)});
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
samples=40,
samples y=1,
smooth,
] ( x , -2 , {f(\x,0)});
\addplot3[
domain=-2:2,
samples=40,
samples y=1,
smooth,
] ( x , -2 , {f(\x,1)});
\draw[->, thick] (0,-2,0) -- node[font=\tiny, pos=0.7, right=-2pt]{$W_{\text{max}}$} (0,-2, {f(0,0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Surface graph]

Comment: It's perfect but how to give the plate a thickness? (noted h in the reference picture)

Comment: It is not possible as such. You can repeat the plot twice with an offset, and clip it to the rectangle, but I doubt that you will be able to see a small difference in the height of the interior and exterior. The only thing really needed is an edge band sticking down from the two front edges. You can use `\fill` or two separate `surf` plots.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! it works by changing the xmax and xmin